# Cake PHP 3+ Query with distinct

Tags: mysql, cakephp, distinct

Is it possible to make a query with several distinct fields in cake php 3+?

This is not working:

```
$model = $this->loadModel('Candys');
        $candys = $model
        ->find('all')
        ->distinct(['maker', 'type', 'color'])
        ->order(['maker' => 'ASC']);
        $this->set(compact('candys'));
```

I need to not show duplicates in html select filter i'm making for 'maker', 'type', 'color'.

Comment: You probably want `->select(['maker', 'type', 'color'])->distinct()`.

Comment: With select->distinct() its showing duplicate fileds. I need to show only one value for each select option field if it is duplicated in the database.

Comment: I'm not fimilar with cake php. You might need to remove `'all'` from `find()`. However - Using `distinct` with arguments in MySQL you are calling for troubles. There is no such thing as `DISTINCT (column_name)` in SQL. There is though `DISTINCT ON (column_name)` in postgres. According to some posts, `distinct([...])` will create a GROUP BY query in MySQL, which can lead to errors with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` mode.

Comment: Yes... it's hard to do what i need because of mysql rules.

Comment: Do you need other columns than 'maker', 'type' and 'color'? If so, they can have different values, and MySQL doesn't know which one to pick. Thus it complains with an error message, which can be read as "I don't know what you want, and probably neither do you!". So you first need to clearly define which rows you want to pick, and then try to find a solution.